# Return an arbitary element from a set that satisfies a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

Is there a way to retrieve any arbitary element from a set that satisfies a particular condition?

For example, if my set has `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}` .

Is there a way to retrieve any arbitary element that is less than 5?

Comment: Use a list comprehension.

Comment: *Arbitrary* or *random*? Arbitrary means you don't care which you get, and any pattern or lack of pattern in the results is fine. An arbitrary choice might choose the same thing every time.

Comment: I meant arbitary

Comment: If you just want an arbitrary choice, going over the whole set is a waste - you could do something like `next(n for n in s if n < 5)` to stop as soon as you find a single match.

Comment: Are you willing to consider a data-structure other than a set? A sorted list? A heap? Set order is *arbitrary*, so you will have to do linear iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `random.choice` a list that filters your set to the choices you want:

```
from random import choice

s = set([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
choice([n for n in s if n < 5])
```

Of course, if you want all the items less than 5, it's just the list:

```
[n for n in s if n < 5]
```

Comment: Yes this works! Thank you :)